# How do I change font size in a docx file python

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, doc

I am trying to create a Finance Log, however I canot change the font size from one size to another without the entire font size of all the text changing.

I want "Finance Log" and "Created On..." to be in 48 and "Log Begins:" to be in 24.

```
Tstyle = doc.styles['Normal']
font = Tstyle.font
font.name = "Nunito Sans"
font.size = Pt(48)
Title = doc.add_paragraph()
TRun = Title.add_run("Finance Log")
TRun.bold = True
CurrentDate= datetime.datetime.now()
FormattedDate= CurrentDate.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
FCreated = Title.add_run("\nFile Created On "+FormattedDate)
Fstyle = doc.styles['Heading 1']
font = Fstyle.font
font.name = "Nunito Sans"
font.size = Pt(24)
FLog = doc.add_paragraph()
FinanceTitle = FLog.add_run("Log Begins:")
doc.save(path_to_docx)
```

I have tried multiple things such as creating a new style, setting the new style to a heading etc...

I am aware of [Set paragraph font in python-docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884703/set-paragraph-font-in-python-docx) however I could not resolve the problem from this

Comment: Assign the font `.size` to a `run` object. I haven't worked with styles, but I suspect it's the same thing, assign the style to a `run`. This should be the same idea as [how to apply bold or underlining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53638832/bold-underlining-and-iterations-with-python-docx/53639019#53639019)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I canot change the font size from one size to another without the entire font size of all the text changing.

That's because you're changing the underlying font size of the `style` objects:

```
Tstyle = doc.styles['Normal']
font = Tstyle.font  # << this line assigns font = doc.styles['Normal'].font
```

So, you're not working with some generic "font" property, you're working with the font that belongs to the named style "Normal". And so:

```
font.name = "Nunito Sans"
font.size = Pt(48)  # << this line changes the font size of doc.styles['Normal']
```

Untested, but try something like:

```
TStyle, FStyle = doc.styles['Normal'], doc.styles['Heading 1']
for style in (TStyle, FStyle):
    style.font.name = "Nunito Sans"
TStyle.font.size = Pt(48)
FStyle.font.size = Pt(24)


Title = doc.add_paragraph()
Title.style = TStyle
TRun = Title.add_run("Finance Log")
TRun.bold = True

FCreated = Title.add_run("\nFile Created On {0}".format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%y')))

FLog = doc.add_paragraph()
FLog.style = FStyle
FinanceTitle = FLog.add_run("Log Begins:")
doc.save(path_to_docx)
```